# How to create a for or while loop for nested SELECT statement using SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry guys but I think I'm stuck in the weeds.  Is there a way to execute a FOR or WHILE LOOP for each value in the nested SELECT statements for the values in the IN function?  **I am needing to get the MAX(RESUBMISSION) value for each 'DATE RANGE' in the IN FUNCTION**.  Right now I get 1 MAX value for all the values in the IN function which is NOT correct.

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Here is my ENTIRE WHERE clause:

```
WHERE r425.SCHYEAR IN('2010-2011', '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', 
'2014-2015', '2015-2016')
AND r425.SUBMISSION = 3
AND r425.RESUBMISSION != 5
AND r425.RESUBMISSION = (**SELECT MAX(RESUBMISSION) FROM [Peims_SIS].[dbo].RECORD425 WHERE SCHYEAR IN('2010-2011', '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', '2014-2015', '2015-2016') AND SUBMISSION = 3**)
AND r425.DISACTIONCODE IN ('05', '06')
AND r101.SUBMISSION = 3
AND r101.RESUBMISSION = (**SELECT MAX(RESUBMISSION) FROM [Peims_SIS].[dbo].RECORD101 WHERE SCHYEAR IN('2010-2011', '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', '2014-2015', '2015-2016') AND SUBMISSION = 3**)   
AND r020.SUBMISSION = 3
```

Comment: To improve the chances of getting helpful advice (and decreasing the guessing on the part of the people answering), it's best to include table structures, sample data that shows your issue, expected output given the sample data, and the *full* query that you've tried along with what isn't working about it. If you're getting an error message then you should include the **exact** error message. For more information, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for this info Tom.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop.   You just need to correlate your subqueries with your outer query.

Here is an example of the first one:

```
AND r425.RESUBMISSION = (
  SELECT MAX(RESUBMISSION) 
  FROM [Peims_SIS].[dbo].RECORD425 r425b 
  WHERE r425b.SCHYEAR=r425.SCHYEAR
  AND SUBMISSION = 3
)
```

That first line of the WHERE clause in my subquery makes the subquery get the `MAX(Resubmission)` for the current `SCHYEAR` that the outer query is looking at.

Comment: Thanks Tab.  I appreciate your time and help.  I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join instead of using a where.

Remember in SQL you don't have loops, you have rows.

Something like this:

```
FROM TABLE X
JOIN (SELECT RESUBMISSION 
      FROM [Peims_SIS].[dbo].RECORD425 
      WHERE SCHYEAR IN('2010-2011', '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', '2014-2015', '2015-2016')
       AND SUBMISSION = 3) A ON r425.RESUBMISSION = A.RESUBMISSION
JOIN (SELECT RESUBMISSION 
      FROM [Peims_SIS].[dbo].RECORD101 
      WHERE SCHYEAR IN('2010-2011', '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', '2014-2015', '2015-2016') 
        AND SUBMISSION = 3) B ON AND r101.RESUBMISSION = B.RESUBMISSION
WHERE r425.SCHYEAR IN('2010-2011', '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', 
'2014-2015', '2015-2016')
AND r425.SUBMISSION = 3
AND r425.RESUBMISSION != 5
AND r425.DISACTIONCODE IN ('05', '06')
AND r101.SUBMISSION = 3
AND r020.SUBMISSION = 3
```

Comment: I don't see how this achieves the goal of getting the MAX().